Update Microsoft Office list with data from another list with Power Automate
I'm having such a hard time figuring out how Microsoft Office Power Automate works with Lists.
I havs two lists: Contacts and Call Log.
I'd like to update one column "Lastest Call Date" in Contacts list with the value from Call Log list. Basically, Call Log list has various logs of recent calls with clients (that are in Contacts list) and thei respective dates. I'd like to update the Latest Call Date column for each client with the lastest call date from last register in Call Log.
I have tried to create a power automate flow, initiating with Manually Trigger and get items from Call Log. But I don't know how tl get only the last register date for each client. And then I'd have to run another flow to find the same contact in Contacts list and update the field there with the latest date.
Contacts list:

Name | Last Call Date
Client 1 | xxx
Client 2 | yyy


Call Log List:
Client | Call Details | Call Date
Client 1 | aaa aaa | 07/29/2024
Client 1 | bbb bbb | 05/29/2024
Client 2 | eee eee | 03/20/2024

So, I'd like to update Contacts list column date with the date of the last call registered in the Call Log list. That would be very simple programmatically or using excel. Would have to loop the call log list, match client id, get the last call date and add that date to the Last Call Date field in Contacts list.
Thanks

can you share what you have tried? what you get vs what you expect to get?

Hi, I was just able to get the items from one list. I tried using filter query for filtering last calls only, but no success. Then I tried to create another flow to run thorugh each record and store the value of the date in a variable. But I was stuck. I don't understand the logic of power automate and lists.

refer to this when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

provide some sample input data to reproduce the issue, and what you expect the output to be

Juat updated the post. Thanks
